# LSTM object detection tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, lstm, object-detection

*Long story short:*

**How to prepare data for lstm object detection retraining of the tensorflow master github implementation.**

*Long story:*

Hi all,
I recently found implementation a lstm object detection algorithm based on this **paper**:
http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Liu_Mobile_Video_Object_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf

at the tensorflow model master **github repository** (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lstm_object_detection)

I would like to **retrain** this implementation on my **own dataset** to evaluate the lstm improvement to other algorithms like SSD. But I keep struggling on how to prepare the data for the training. I've tried the config file of the authors and tried to prepare the data similar to the object-detection-api and also tried to use the same procedure as the *inputs/seq_dataset_builder_test.py* or *inputs/tf_sequence_example_decoder_test.py* does. Sadly the github Readme does not provide any information. Someone else created an issue with a similar question on the github repo (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5869) but the authors did not provide a helpful answer yet. I tried to contact the authors via email a month ago, but didn't got a response. I've also searched the internet but found no solution. Therefore I desperately write to you!

***Is anybody out there who can explain how to prepare the data for the retraining and how to actually run the retraining.***

Thank you for reading, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: The more I search for information about this model, the more frustrated I get. The algorithm and the idea are cool, but the support to the code is non existent and their code is broken, undocumented and unusable...

Comment: It is almost impossible to give you good advice if I do not know the database or the model. Usually, implementing a new model based on a research paper is quite difficult because of all the math involved. I advise you to improve your coding/math skills before tackling this problem or ask a professional in an academic setting.

Comment: Long story short - good pun :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same error message as what was in the github issue, then the problem is that you don't have all of the necessary libraries installed.

https://pypi.org/project/google3/

Ideally they should have provided a requirements.txt file to install everything, but it seems like they did not. Another possibility could be given here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2576

And that you have to change some of the code to point to the internal g3 folders.